# Redis VS Redis Enterprises VS Redis AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have 2 questions:

1. Currently I'm using REDIS (non enterprise/non paid) but one of the team is recommending to use Redis from AWS. I feel its an overhead on organization. I want to know the pros and cons of using AWS Redis. I have done some research but cannot find concreate answers yet.
2. Other than that can anyone please help that what is difference between REDIS(Non paid) and REDIS Enterprise(paid version) in layman term?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I will answer regarding Amazon ElastiCache.

### Pros of using Amazon ElastiCache:

1. Cost optimization: Migrating Redis workloads to ElastiCache can help reduce costs associated with self-managed Redis deployments. With ElastiCache, you pay only for the resources you consume, allowing you to scale up or down based on your needs. It eliminates the need for upfront hardware investments and reduces operational overhead.
2. Managed service: ElastiCache is a fully managed service, meaning AWS handles administrative tasks such as hardware provisioning, patching, and backups. This frees up your team's time, allowing them to focus on other critical tasks rather than managing infrastructure.
3. Scalability and high availability: ElastiCache offers automatic scaling capabilities, allowing you to adjust the size of your Redis cluster based on demand. It also provides built-in high availability features, including automatic node replacement and multi-AZ deployments, ensuring your Redis workloads are highly available and reliable.
4. Security and compliance: ElastiCache integrates with AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) for authentication and authorization. It also supports encryption at rest and transit, helping you meet security and compliance requirements.

### Cons of using Amazon ElastiCache:

1. Limited customization: ElastiCache provides a managed environment, which means you have limited control over the underlying infrastructure and configuration options compared to self-managed Redis deployments. For certain customization you may have to schedule an appointment with customer support.
2. Learning curve: While ElastiCache simplifies many aspects of Redis management, there may still be a learning curve involved in understanding and utilizing the features and capabilities of the service. This could require some upfront investment in training and familiarization.
3. Cost considerations: While ElastiCache can optimize costs, it's important to carefully analyze your specific workload requirements and compare them to the pricing model of ElastiCache. Depending on your usage patterns and resource needs, there may be cases where self-managed Redis deployments could be more cost-effective.

Overall, Amazon ElastiCache offers numerous benefits, including cost optimization, managed services, scalability, and security. It's essential to evaluate your specific use case and weigh the advantages against customization limitations, learning curve, and cost considerations.

Check out the blog for more information: [optimize-costs-by-moving-your-self-managed-open-source-software-oss-redis-workloads-to-amazon-elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/optimize-costs-by-moving-your-self-managed-open-source-software-oss-redis-workloads-to-amazon-elasticache/)